# Attribute table Does Not Show Any Lat Long Field in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, gps, attribute-table

I had import shapefiles data which is a point features from GPS receiver. The points are well on pointed on the ArcGIS display, but when I open each attributes table, there is no field show the latitude and longitude of the points while the points were shown at display in a correct location abse on my georeferenced map. Why? The attributes only show the ObjectID, Shape, and Comments.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Comment: Coordinate values are a property of the geometry ("Shape" column).  Since you didn't describe your import procedure, it's difficult to know what options you might have had along the way, but now you could use [AddXY](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm).  It may help in the future if you stop using "Lat Long" to describe coordinate values and start thinking "Lon Lat" -- "Long" is a datatype, and therefore often a reserved word, and the order will prevent you from flipping axis.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is the classical layout of the Shapefile, or geodata in general. The coordinates are not shown here since it would be not a good idea when you have for example a polygon with hundreds of points. Thats why the underlying geometry is stored differently.

For the shapefile it is stored in the .shp file. Think of it as a small database with relations of tables with polygons/lines/points to tables of coordinates.

To have columns that are showing you latitude and longtitude you have to add columns for them and fill them with the values:

You go to the attribute table and there to options "Add field" and give it float or double as data-type. The right-click the new columns and go to "calculate geometry" and choose X-Coordinate/Y-Coordinate. Then the field is populated with the latitude and longtitude values.